# Define Boolean TRUE/FALSE variable in R function

Tags: r, function, variables, boolean

I have built a function in R, which computes a series of calculations over a file input.

Some of these calculations require a 1000-fold permutation of the input, so that if the input consists of few elements, the time consumed for calculation is ok, but including the 1000-fold permutation, and with a large number of elements to evaluate, the time consumed can go up to not desired times of R computation.

I would like to enclosure these variables into a TRUE/FALSE statement, so that by default this is set to FALSE, but the user can include it by putting a TRUE when declaring the function.

Say:

```
function_name <- function(a, b, c, d = FALSE) {

       #calculate variable 1
                .
                .
                .


       #calculate variable 2
                .       
                .
                .


       #calculate variables with so much time to calculate 


       #calculate variable n
                .
                .
                .

      table <- as.data.frame(cbind(1,2,3,......))

      return(table)

}
```

This function returns a table with columns as variables and rows as items introduced to calculate the variables over them.

What I want to achieve is that, id d = FALSE, function does not calculate the so much time consuming variables, and goes ahead to calculate the rest of the light variables, returning a table without these variables not calculated. But if d = TRUE, these variables are calculated and the resulting table consists of all the variables.

I know that I shoudl define an if (d == FALSE) do not do this, if (d == TRUE), do this, but I do not know how to implement this inside my function... which consists of many variables calculations.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: You can use an ifelse(d==FALSE, foo, bar), where foo is code that execute when d is FALSE, and bar is code that execute if d is TRUE. The foo and bar can be some other functions, and foo is that shorter function whereas bar is some “more time consuming” code

Comment: Use `if` not `ifelse` in this case. `ifelse` has some nasty length(output) == length(condition) check constraints.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what (a subset of) your input and output parameters might look like? Thanks.